# Scala MongoDB Chaining Methods

Tags: mongodb, scala, method-chaining

i'd like to ask for your help about beautifying client code.

Let's say I have some basic methods for MongoDB retrieval:

```
 def find(dbo:DBObject):MongoCursor =
    mongoColl.find(dbo)

  def Sort(cursor: MongoCursor, sortFun: DBObject): MongoCursor =
    cursor.sort(sortFun)

  def Limit(cursor: MongoCursor, number: Int): MongoCursor = cursor.limit(number)

  def Offset(cursor: MongoCursor, number: Int): MongoCursor = cursor.skip(number)

  def toList(cursor: MongoCursor): List[A] =
   cursor map (readConverter(_)) toList
```

and i wanna chain them together in different ways (let say i wanna perform some limited searchs, some sorted searchs, just like a decorator basically). how would you do it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use an *implicit value class* to enrich the `MongoCursor`:

```
object ImplicitClassContainer {
  implicit class RichMongoCursor(val mc: MongoCursor) extends AnyVal {
    def sort(sortFun: DBObject): MongoCursor = mc.sort(sortFun)

    def limit(number: Int): MongoCursor = mc.limit(number)

    def offset(number: Int): MongoCursor = mc.skip(number)
  }

}
```

to be used like this

```
  import ImplicitClassContainer._

  def x(mc: MongoCursor): MongoCursor = {
    mc.offset(25).limit(25)
  }
```

Basically it's the same pattern which is used to add functionality to `Array`:
You get additional functions in "flow style", but it's still a `MongoCursor`. As it is an *implicit value class*, no additional instance of an object is created at run-time.

Comment: Quite an interesting approach i have to say. I was personally thinking more about a "andThen" apporach but this looks pretty cool as well